# How to track session length using Firebase + Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to calculate average session length using BigQuery for my Firebase + Unity setup.

I followed tutorials for default Unity setup. I can gather data, and see where new sessions begin.

However, I can't seem to find proper session length. I'm able to gather the time between sessions, however I can't seem to find an event which signals sessions expiring (I know they do after 30 minutes of inactivity).

My alternative path has proven a bit difficult...I attempted to get the last interaction event when a session starts, and subtract the event_previous_timestamp from it, no luck because session_start isn't actually the first event thrown when starting a new session!

Here is the query I attempted:

```
#standardsql
SELECT event_name, session_length, time_between_sessions
FROM 
  (SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_name, event_timestamp, 
event_previous_timestamp,
  LAG(event_timestamp, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY 
event_timestamp) AS last_triggered_event,
  (LAG(event_timestamp, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER 
BY event_timestamp) - event_previous_timestamp) / 60000000 AS 
session_length,
  (event_timestamp - event_previous_timestamp) / 60000000 AS 
time_between_sessions
  FROM `insertyourtablename`
  ORDER BY event_timestamp)
WHERE 
event_name = "session_start"
```

I hope there is an easier way to do this, or I'm close! Thank you :)

Comment: Is it important that you get the total average session length rather than the average time that a user engages with the app per session?

Comment: Either way, there are changes coming that should make your (our) life easier: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html

Comment: The average user engagement would be just as useful, how would I calculate that?

Comment: Also if you know when those changes are coming? :)

Comment: @Vesper please dm or answer here if you know either of these answers, would be so grateful

Comment: I'm not sure what the best approach is. I tried summing up engagement_time_msec (user_engagement) for users present in session_start but the result was confusing to me. Many users had several sessions started but no/close to no engagement time.

Comment: I'm getting similar results. They initially made sense until I realized they were milliseconds